# Get bot-side code in bot framework - webchat github repo

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, spfx

I am creating an SPFx webpart to create a chat window for SharePoint Online. Basically Azure bot service is to be used in conjunction with QnA maker service and the resultant bot should be used with the chat window. I have successfully transformed the sample available at [Microsft/BotFramework-webchat](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/12.customization-minimizable-web-chat) github repository to create a minimizable chat window and this is working properly.

I want to show a welcome message to user as soon as user get connected with bot and for that a sample is available at [/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) *'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT'* is added in store but now i am not getting it that how to access 'bot-side' code to post a welcome message when above mentioned activity is received by the bot.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2120#issuecomment-516056614

Comment: I think i need to go to the 'build' tab of my bot service and write events there. is it correct?

Comment: Are you requesting a token to initiate the conversation? How did you make your bot? Is it running locally or is it in Azure?

Comment: It's in Azure, created Azure bot service through portal and using direct line secret to generate a token.

Comment: Can you add your code for requesting a token? If you add the user id to the body of the request, it should trigger the welcome message in onMembersAdded handler before the user messages the bot.